# Not able to install cocoapods in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I am currently installing cocoapods in my Project.i am using **xcode 6.3.1** and OS is EL Capitan version is **10.11.6**

i am following this steps

- sudo gem install cocoapods
- pod setup
- open terminal and give path of our project
- pod init

when i do pod init i am getting error.i have attached screenshot.

[image: ScreenShot of terminal]

please go through it and please let me know.thanks in advance

Comment: You have to update your cocoaPod to latest version, May be you are using old version. Can you tell me you Cocoapod version and Also Pod file.

Comment: You can just create an empty file, open in Xcode, and add the pod code there instead of using `pod init`

Comment: @Aashish1aug "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-1.2.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
"

Comment: @Tj3n i create textfile and move to project folder.when i do pod install.i am getting error "no podfile found"

Comment: @Aashish1aug i am installing pod from scratch in new project

Comment: Good, For installing try this: sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

Comment: You have to open the info of the text, and delete the `.txt`

Comment: check pod --version

Comment: @Aashish1aug same issue

Comment: Then check in which directory you are creating your pod file, you should create pod file in your app root folder, adjacent to xcodeproj file.

Comment: @KD, you have use the provide command before pod init in your project. Basically this problem is come with me also and Found it related to Mac OS.

Comment: @Aashish1aug Ok.so you solve it?than share

Comment: You can try to uninstall your cocoa pod setup and Again install this by following the reference link as I have given in answer.

Comment: I have solved on my system by just reInstall the cocoa pod in bin location as    suggested to you.:)

Comment: @Aashish1aug ok.thanks.let me try asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for CocoaPod issue.

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

reference here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3736

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sudo gem uninstall nanaimo
```

just delete one of the nanaimo, and keep the latest version.