# Unable to install Cocoapods in xcode 9.2 project

Tags: ios, cocoapods, xcode9.2

I am trying to install pod in my Xcode 9.2 project but when i enter command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

it gives me the following error.

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

After some research on google i found out that my opensssl version is old due to which this error is coming. But i am unable to find any perfect solutions for this error.I hope some other people also must have came across this issue.

Comment: just try "pod install" command

Comment: @aBilal17 it will give [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Comment: Then its is clear, just create a pod file in project and run this command "pod install"

Comment: @aBilal17 broo i am trying to install pod in my project as mentioned in my question the command "pod install" will work after i install pod in my project.

Comment: Please check my answer for this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973369/not-able-to-install-cocoapods-in-xcode/42973827#42973827

Comment: @Aashish1aug Buddy i saw your post prior to posting question, its not working for me. meanwhile i am searching very aggressively on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution i installed homebrew and then i followed the procedure of installing cocoapods after that.